# Using CloudFront function to restrict S3 site access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have static sites that sit on S3 and are served via CloudFront. I need to restrict access to a list of IP addresses.

The main option I'd seen on the internet was to use WAF. I have used CloudFront functions to achieve similar functionality.

Are there any significant benefits I'm missing out on by not using WAF over CF functions if my aim is solely to restrict public access? (i.e. if I do not care about other WAF features)

Here's what my cloud function does.

```
if (viewer request ip not in my list) {
    return custom 403 response
}
return request
```

Comment: If you don't care about other WAF features, and this does the job for you, then what is the issue? WAF's features are documented readily online.

Comment: WAF has additional costs, so if CloudFront is meeting your requirements then it would seem sensible to remain as-is.